# \fbox without padding

Tags: graphics

Hi I want to use `\fbox{}` within a `figure`. Because the graphic has allot white parts I want to add a border to it for better view. But I recognised that `\fbox{}` adds a padding to the graphic which I don't like/want. I want the border on (or +1px) where the graphic "ends".

For illustrating purpose, this is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}

  \crule[yellow]{2cm}{1cm} 

  \fbox{\crule[yellow]{2cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

Gives me this:

[image]

Obviously in my proper code there is s.th. like this `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth] {img/file.ext}}` insted of the yellow box.

Any ideas how to remove the padding inside the frame?

Comment: The space on the right edge is simply the space in your `\fbox` command. But you want all of the surrounding space removed?

Comment: Simply use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}`.

Comment: @AlanMunn whoops. I removed the space. But yes all space (the ~3px space) like the answer shows below :)

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks, adding % around the \fbox{ ... } lines fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The border is determined by the `\fboxsep` length:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\crule[3][black]{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}

\crule[yellow]{2cm}{1cm}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fbox{\crule[yellow]{2cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: for the OPs use case this will still make a box overfull by 2\fboxrule  so may want to use \frame rather than \fbox, or put a `\hspace*{-\fboxrule}` either side